# transformación XSL

Tags: html, xml, xsl, xslt

estoy realizando un ejercicio de conversión y adaptación de XML y tengo un par de dudas, en primer lugar os copio los códigos:

```
**XML:**

    <notas>
     <alumno convocatoria="Septiembre">
      <nombre>Carlos</nombre>
      <apellidos>Amaya Arozamena</apellidos>
      <matricula>m019843</matricula>
      <cuestionarios>8.0</cuestionarios>
      <tareas>8.0</tareas>
      <examen>6.0</examen>
      <final>8.0</final>
    </alumno>
    <alumno convocatoria="Junio">
      <nombre>Jose</nombre>
      <apellidos>Muñoz Soto</apellidos>
      <matricula>m019872</matricula>
      <cuestionarios>7.0</cuestionarios>
      <tareas>9.0</tareas>
      <examen>7.0</examen>
      <final>8.5</final>
    </alumno>
    <alumno convocatoria="Junio">
      <nombre>Ana</nombre>
      <apellidos>Martinez de la Fuente</apellidos>
      <matricula>m097215</matricula>
      <cuestionarios>8.0</cuestionarios>
      <tareas>9.0</tareas>
      <examen>9.0</examen>
      <final>8.5</final>
   </alumno>
    <alumno convocatoria="Septiembre">
      <nombre>Roberto</nombre>
      <apellidos>Carrera Fernández</apellidos>
      <matricula>m059312</matricula>
      <cuestionarios>6.0</cuestionarios>
      <tareas>7.0</tareas>
      <examen>6.0</examen>
      <final>6.5</final>
    </alumno>
    <alumno convocatoria="Septiembre">
      <nombre>Concepción</nombre>
      <apellidos>Lalinde Priego</apellidos>
      <matricula>m034093</matricula>
      <cuestionarios>4.0</cuestionarios>
      <tareas>3.0</tareas>
      <examen>2.0</examen>
      <final>3.0</final>
    </alumno>
    <alumno convocatoria="Junio">
      <nombre>Esther</nombre>
      <apellidos>Pereda</apellidos>
      <matricula>m938762</matricula>
      <cuestionarios>2.0</cuestionarios>
      <tareas>3.0</tareas>
      <examen>2.0</examen>
      <final>2.5</final>
      </alumno>
    </notas>
```

**XSL**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title><xsl:template select="notas"/></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>NOTAS</h1>
                <h2>CONVOCATORIA DE JUNIO</h2>
                <h3>Alumnos</h3>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="notas/alumno"/>             
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="alumno">
        <p>
            <table align="center" border="1">
                <td><b>Nombre</b>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="nombre"/></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b>Apellidos</b>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="apellidos"/></p>
                </td>
                <td><b>Tareas</b>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="tareas"/></p>
                </td>
                <td><b>Cuestionarios</b>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="cuestionarios"/></p>
                </td>
                <td><b>Nota Final</b>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="final"/></p>
                </td>
            </table>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>


    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Tal como lo tengo, he conseguido mostrar en web los datos de todos los alumnos en una tabla, sin embargo, necesito filtrar únicamente los de la convocatoria "Junio". Lo intento modificando la siguiente línea:

```
 <xsl:template match="alumno[@convocatoria='Junio']">
```

Pero no hace lo que quiero. ¿Donde tendría que hacer el filtro del atributo de la convocatoria para que coja solo los de Junio?

Por otro lado, necesito mostrar las notas en letra según el intervalo de éstas (>9 (SOBRESALIENTE), >=7(NOTABLE)... etc), pero tengo la duda del código en sí, y en cual de los dos documentos debo ponerlo, si en el XML o el XSL.

A ver si me podéis orientar un poco, gracias.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente tu problema viene dado porque no está encontrando correctamente quien es el elemento padre y el hijo.

Puedes probar con estas dos formas:

**Forma 1:**

```
<xsl:template match="//alumno[@convocatoria='Junio']">
```

Con `//` lo que estás indicando es que coja todo desde la raíz hasta llegar a alumno.

**Forma 2:**

```
<xsl:template match="notas/alumno[@convocatoria='Junio']">
```

Siguiendo el árbol raíz hasta llegar a alumno y el atributo de dicho elemento.

Con respecto a las notas, tienes que usar `<xsl:if>` para indicar condiciones, por ejemplo:

```
<xsl:if test="notas/alumno/notas >= 9"> Sobresaliente </xsl:if>
```

Etc, hasta cumplir con todas las condiciones.

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias, funcionó! Respecto al xsl:if, tendría que ir dentro del <p><xsl:value-of select="final"/></p> o al revés, el xsl:value debe ir dentro del xsl:if?

Comment: Si son varias condiciones, sería mas correcto utilizar <xsl:choose> para este cas?

Comment: Cierto @rodic también podría usarse `<xsl:choose>`, ambas podrían valer.